# Trying to read from XML inside timer but it's not working

Tags: c#, xml, timer

I want to print the number 1 to 6 every 5 seconds, and stop timer when it reaches the end of the list.

**Result of print:**

> 1
>   2
>   3
>   4
>   5
>   6

**Code:**

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{        
    List<int> l = new List<int>() {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    XElement xdoc = XElement.Load("../../XMLFile1.xml");
    xdoc.Element("num").Value = "0";
    xdoc.Element("max").Value = l.Count.ToString();
    xdoc.Save("../../XMLFile1.xml");
    Timer t = new Timer(printnum, null, 0, 5000);           
}

public static void printnum(Object o)
{
    try
    {
        XElement xdoc = XElement.Load("../../XMLFile1.xml");
        int num = int.Parse(xdoc.Element("num").Value);
        int max = int.Parse(xdoc.Element("max").Value);
        if (num<max)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(num);
            num += 1;
            xdoc.Element("num").Value = num.ToString();
            xdoc.Save("../../XMLFile1.xml");
        }          
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
}
```

This is my XML file named  XMLFile1.xml the `num` is running number and `max` is the list max number:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <num>0</num>
    <max>0</max>
</root>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Why do you need the xml file?

Comment: i want to print the numbers 1-6 every 5 sec, how i will know in the func printnum() what is the next number to print?

Comment: So every five seconds, a new number will be printed?

Comment: Can you add why this code is not currently working / an error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that your application terminates after the `Main` method exists. This happens because the Timer will execute code on a different Thread. To fix your issue, simply pause the main thread by doing something like reading a line from the console:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{        
    List<int> l = new List<int>() {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    XElement xdoc = XElement.Load("../../XMLFile1.xml");
    xdoc.Element("num").Value = "0";
    xdoc.Element("max").Value = l.Count.ToString();
    xdoc.Save("../../XMLFile1.xml");
    Timer t = new Timer(printnum, null, 0, 5000);    

    Console.ReadLine(); //Read a line from the console which forces the main thread to wait
}
```

However, your requirement can be done without using an Xml file, here is an example:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int number = 1;

    Timer timer = null;

    timer = new Timer((s) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(number++);

        if (number == 7)
            timer.Dispose();

    }, null, 0, 5000);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Or even simpler, you don't need a timer:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int number = 1; number <= 6; number ++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(number);
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

Here is another version that is asynchronous:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Print(1, 6, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)); //This doesn't cause the thread to wait

    //Do something else if you want
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private async static Task Print(int from, int to, TimeSpan every)
{
    for (int number = from; number <= to; number ++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(number);
        await Task.Delay(every);
    }
}
```

Comment: when the line Thread.Sleep(5000) exeuting  the other program keep running  ?

Comment: Which other program? Can you explain?

Comment: if i implement  the loop in my site the the site keep running and working?

Comment: Is this a web site? This seems to be a Console Application.

Comment: i want to implement this func in my site

Comment: a Web site? Please give more context

Comment: i get ambiguous reference  System.Threading.Tasks.task ,  System.Threading.Tasks.task

Comment: Aren't these two the same thing? Can you update your question with more context about the code that you currently have?

Answer (score 0):

Also i am not sure what you are trying to do, i am sure that the timers is not triggering because it is deleted when the main is over. It is only a local variable. I also found some others things and tryed to fix it:

```
class Test
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    public void DoIt()
    {
        List<int> l = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
        XElement xdoc = XElement.Load("../../XMLFile1.xml");
        xdoc.Element("num").Value = "0";
        xdoc.Element("max").Value = l.Count.ToString();
        xdoc.Save("../../XMLFile1.xml");

        timer.Interval = 5000;
        timer.Tick += printnum;
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    public void printnum(object sender, EventArgs ev)
    {
        try
        {
            XElement xdoc = XElement.Load("../../XMLFile1.xml");
            int num = int.Parse(xdoc.Element("num").Value);
            int max = int.Parse(xdoc.Element("max").Value);
            num += 1;
            Console.WriteLine(num);
            if (num < max)
            {
                xdoc.Element("num").Value = num.ToString();
                xdoc.Save("../../XMLFile1.xml");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Finish");
                timer.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static AutoResetEvent autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            State state = new State();
            state.l  = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
            state.index = 0;
            state.xdoc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            state.num = state.xdoc.Descendants("num").FirstOrDefault();
            state.xdoc.Descendants("max").FirstOrDefault().Value = state.l.LastOrDefault().ToString();
            Timer t = new Timer(printnum, state, 0, 5000);
            autoEvent.WaitOne();
            t.Dispose();

        }
        public class State
        {
            public XElement num { get; set; }
            public XDocument xdoc { get; set; }
            public List<int> l { get; set; }
            public int index { get; set; }
        }

        public static void printnum(Object o)
        {
            State state = o as State;
            try
            {
                int num = state.l[state.index++];
                Console.WriteLine(num);
                state.num.Value = num.ToString();
                state.xdoc.Save(FILENAME);
                if (state.index >= state.l.Count)
                {
                    autoEvent.Set();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
​
```